# Spark accumulator giving twice the sum

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a piece of code where I am declaring an accumulator in the parent class. I have a function in this parent class which maps a DataFrame to a function defined in the child classes. I have the accumulator increment by 1 in the child class function, so that every time the mapping function is called the accumulator increments by 1. So if the mapping function is called x times, accumulator should hold the value x. However I am seeing accumulator shows approx 2x on logging. The code looks something like below:

```
abstract class A{
  var accum = sparkCtx.accumulator(0)
  def func1(df) {
    var df2 = df.map(func2)
    func3(df2)
  }
  def func3(df2) {
    //filter operation on df2 which basically makes the count 0
    var df3 = df2.filter("Condition which never satisfies")
    var df4 = df3.map(func2)
}
class B extends A{
  def func2() {
    accum.add(1)
   //return df
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Most likely, `func1` is called twice (perhaps, with different arguments) .. you'd have to show (a lot) more of the code for it to be a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
The root problem with your code (aside from overusing `vars`) is that `func1` is side-effecting. Having `accum` as a  mutable class member whose state changes when a method is invoked is fundamentally what causes all of the badness you experience here.

Comment: what could be a better way to achieve the goal of counting the requests here?

Have verified that func1 is being called just once but it calls another function func3 which has a map call to func2 but the df being passed for that is empty. Updating the code to reflect this

Comment: I am not sure what are the "requests" you are counting  ... Seems like `df.count()` would do what you are looking for 

Comment: there is actually a logic in func2 which does not make it a add(1) call every time. func2 call could result in either adding 1 or 2 to the accumulator and I need this accumulator value later in the code to compare against a request breach limit

Comment: I dunno ... then maybe you are adding 2 too often 
Look, your question is essentially this: "I have some code that I won't show, with some logic that I won't explain, and it doesn't work. Why?"